# Extend function to multivariate situation

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

Let's define big outliers as observations that match inequality :

[image]

And small outliers as observations that match inequality :

[image]

I want to write function `replace_outliers(table, std)` which will go though all variables (all columns) and will replace big outliers with upper bound i.e.

[image]

and small outliers with lower bound i.e.

[image]

**My work so far**

What I did is to write function for univariate situation (works only when I have only one column).

```
Function replace_outliers(table As Range, std As Double)
    Dim temp() As Variant
    temp = table.Value
    
    Dim mean As Double
    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(temp)
    
    Dim stdv As Double
    stdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(temp)
    Dim upper_bound As Double
    Dim lower_bound As Double
    upper_bound = std * stdv + mean
    lower_bound = mean - stdv * std
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
        If (temp(i, 1) - mean) / stdv > std Then
            temp(i, 1) = upper_bound
        ElseIf (temp(i, 1) - mean) / stdv < -std Then
            temp(i, 1) = lower_bound
        End If
    Next
    replace_outliers = temp
End Function
```

Example :

[image]

However I'm not sure what should I do to extend this for mulitvariate situation (i.e. to apply `replace_outliers(table, std)` for each column in input table provided. Do you have any idea how it can be performed ?

**EDIT**

I tried to loop it across columns. This is my work :

```
Function outliers_std_1(table As Range, std As Double)
    Dim temp() As Variant
    temp = table.Value
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To UBound(temp, 2)
        Dim mean As Double
        mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table.Columns(j))
    
        Dim stdv As Double
        stdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(table.Columns(j))
        Dim upper_bound As Double
        Dim lower_bound As Double
        upper_bound = std * stdv + mean
        lower_bound = mean - stdv * std
    
        Dim i As Long
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(temp, j)
            If (temp(i, j) - mean) / stdv > std Then
                temp(i, j) = upper_bound
         ElseIf (temp(i, j) - mean) / stdv < -std Then
                temp(i, j) = lower_bound
         End If
         Next
    Next
    outliers_std_1 = temp
End Function
```

However I get `#ARG`! error when trying to run it on data below :

[image]

Comment: `temp` is a 2D array so you can easily add an inner (or maybe outer) loop over columns, instead of the hard-coded `1`. See [Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: The inner loop:`Dim j as Long` and `For j = 1 to Ubound(temp,2)` then replace all the `temp(i,1)` with `temp(i,j)`

Comment: Hmm I tried to use your tips to loop it after column but I didn't manage to do it properly. I updated my question. Did I miss something ?

Comment: `mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table.Columns(j))` etc

Comment: Hmmm I adjusted my code with calculation mean and standard deviation but I still see #ARG!. Please have a look at my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested:

```vb
Function outliers_std_1(table As Range, std As Double)
    Dim temp As Variant, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim mean As Double, stdv As Double
    Dim upper_bound As Double
    Dim lower_bound As Double
    
    temp = table.Value
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(temp, 2)
        
        mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table.Columns(j))
        stdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(table.Columns(j))
        upper_bound = mean + (std * stdv)
        lower_bound = mean - (stdv * std)
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
            If temp(i, j) < lower_bound Then
                   temp(i, j) = lower_bound
            ElseIf temp(i, j) > upper_bound Then
                   temp(i, j) = upper_bound
            End If
        Next
    Next
    outliers_std_1 = temp
End Function
```